# Merge multi strings and create new string with set max parameters value

Tags: vbscript

I have a string that splitted by `*` (stars) and I want to merge all items and create a new string with max value.
How can get max value for new string?

```
Function MergeAccessArray()
  f_AccessArray = "projects@dnProjectsPatterning=0|dnProjectsSendReport=1#workplans@dnWorkplansAdd=0|dnWorkplansGrouping=1*projects@dnProjectsPatterning=1|dnProjectsSendReport=3#workplans@dnWorkplansAdd=1|dnWorkplansGrouping=0*projects@dnProjectsPatterning=5|dnProjectsSendReport=1#workplans@dnWorkplansAdd=0|dnWorkplansGrouping=2"

  arrAccessPack = Split(f_AccessArray, "*")
  nArrString = ""
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrAccessPack)
    If i < UBound(arrAccessPack) Then strPipe = "|" Else strPipe = ""
    arrParts = Split(arrAccessPack(i), "#")
    nArrPartString = ""
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrParts)
      'If j < UBound(arrParts) Then iPipe = "|" Else iPipe = ""
      nPart = Split(arrParts(j), "@")(1)
      nArrPartString = nArrPartString & nPart & strPipe
    Next
    nArrString = nArrString & nArrPartString & strPipe
  Next
  nArrString = Replace(nArrString, "||", "|")

  xArrString = Split(nArrString, "|")
  For x = 0 To UBound(xArrString)
  Next
  MergeAccessArray = nArrString
End Function
```

I want this String:

```
arrNewParameters = "projects@dnProjectsPatterning=5|dnProjectsSendReport=3#workplans@dnWorkplansAdd=1|dnWorkplansGrouping=2"
```

Comment: For each parameter, add it to a `Scripting.Dictionary` object with the parametername as key and the value as value. When a parameter already exist, overwrite it with the max value. When you have processed all parameters, rebuild your string with the keys and values from the dictionary.

Comment: tanx sir... I do not have experience of working with dictionaries.. and I think my codes are not optimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow up to my comment, this is an example on how you can use the dictionary to get a list of unique keys and add the highest value to it:

```
s = "projects@dnProjectsPatterning=0|dnProjectsSendReport=1#workplans@dnWorkplansAdd=0|dnWorkplansGrouping=1*projects@dnProjectsPatterning=1|dnProjectsSendReport=3#workplans@dnWorkplansAdd=1|dnWorkplansGrouping=0*projects@dnProjectsPatterning=5|dnProjectsSendReport=1#workplans@dnWorkplansAdd=0|dnWorkplansGrouping=2"

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set re = New RegExp
re.Global = True
re.Pattern = "(\w+)=(\d+)"

Set matches = re.Execute(s)
for each match in matches
    key = match.Submatches(0)
    value = cint(match.Submatches(1))
    if dict.Exists(key) Then
        if value < dict.Item(key) then
            value = dict.Item(key)
        End If
    End If
    dict.Item(key) = value 
next

for each key in dict
    msgbox key & "=" & dict.Item(key)
Next

' output:
' dnProjectsPatterning=5
' dnProjectsSendReport=3
' dnWorkplansAdd=1
' dnWorkplansGrouping=2
```

**Edit:** This is an example that will generate the string for you, but it will only do it for given keys.

```
target = "projects@dnProjectsPatterning={dnProjectsPatterning}|dnProjectsSendReport={dnProjectsSendReport}#dnWorkplansAdd@dnWorkplansAdd={dnWorkplansAdd}|dnWorkplansGrouping={dnWorkplansGrouping}"
for each key in dict
    target = Replace(target, "{" & key & "}", dict.Item(key))
Next
msgbox target
```

Tip: If you expect more and better answers from the SO community, start out with improving you questions and show the effort you already did while trying to get to a solution.

Comment: Tanx AutomatedChaos... for your creative approach...   can you say that reform in accordance with the following format?  
 **"projects@dnProjectsPatterning=5|dnProjectsSendReport=3#workplans@dnWorkplansAdd=1|dnWorkplansGrouping=2"**  
nArr = ""
for each key in dict
    nArr = nArr & key & "=" & dict.Item(key)&"|"
Next
msgbox nArr

Comment: Can you help me for create this string: **"projects@dnProjectsPatterning=5|dnProjectsSendReport=3#work‌​plans@dnWorkplansAdd‌​=1|dnWorkplansGroupi‌​ng=2"**

Comment: **I was troubled** plz help

Comment: @sadrasjd see the edit

Comment: Tanx for your help